# mustInherit class shared function

Tags: vb.net, abstract-class, shared

Hi got a class MustInherit and many instance.

I need a function shared function declared once (normally in the template).
But as a mustInherit, I cant call it. I need to use one of my instance of the class.
Is there another way?

```
Public MustInherit MyBaseClass

...

    public shared function UnknowBaseFunction () as object
    ....


x = InheritsClassByMyBaseClass.UnknowBaseFunction()
```

Comment: Just call `MyBaseClass.UnknowBaseFunction`.

Comment: shared/static functions are not inherited and they are not accessed as a member of a class instance.

Comment: I'm not seeing how this wouldn't work, what error is the compiler giving you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to inherit a shared member so that it also is available through the derived class name.  Obviously, by removing the `Shared` keyword, it will be available in all derived types, but only via instantiated objects, not as a shared method.  If it doesn't make sense to have everything call the method via the base class name, then I would recommend breaking it out into a separate class altogether which is neither in the base class nor the derived classes.